# Suppressing InstallDir UI during Upgrade on wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6, wixlib

I want to suppress the InstallDir UI for upgrade scenario. I will get previously installed path from registry and i just want to suppress the this UI.

Is there  any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed OR APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY</Publish> 
.... 
.... 
.... 
<Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed OR APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY</Publish>
```

Add this code to the custom UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [RegistrySearch Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) to retrieve the path from the registry. If it is loaded correctly you can use the search property to condition the dialog display. [Here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Hide-InstallDirDlg-during-upgrade-td5014310.html) is a similar theread

Comment: Thanks.
I got working by adding this <publish> in custom UI.
 
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed OR APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY</Publish>

....

<Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed OR APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY1</Publish>